# @Test annotation executes alphabetic order

Tags: automated-tests

I am doing automation testing . Where i am using @Test annotaion to test the test cases . It's executing alphabetically so my required test cases are getting ignored . I need order based test execution . How can i achive this .Please help me out with this .

Comment: If you need ordered-based execution your tests probably aren't reliable. A good test would use at most `setUp`/`tearDown`. If you *really* need ordered-based execution you can name your tests `test000_Foo`, `test001_Bar` and so on...

Comment: Thanks .. let me try

Answer (score 1):

yes it worked for me .
I had set the priorities instead .
  @Test(priority=1) 
  public void method1(){

}